# numpy(.ma) array: Number of values since last value change?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a status-signal (measured, of a heatpump) in an numpy.ma-array, together with timestamps. What i want is the lengths of the periods it was on and the length of the periods it was off. (NOT the daily running time or something, that would be easy..)

What i have (exemplary, in fact i have minute-values over 16months..):

```
Time    Value
12:00   0
12:01   1
12:02   1
...
12:29   1
12:30   1
12:31   0
...
12:41   0
12:42   1
...
13:01   1
13:02   0
...and so on
```

And what i want to have as output:

```
running_time_was:
time   value (=minutes)
12:31  30
13:10  20

off_time_was:
time   value (=minutes)
12:42  11

(the exact timestamps doesn't matter so much, but there should be some)
```

I already asked the people i know who know python (they had no idea, neither), and tried to search on the internet, but i just don't know what to search for. So maybe someone could at least give me a hint which words i could type into google? :)

ps: Wow, stackoverflow is fantastic! I was already amazed of the usability as passive user, but the asking interface is even better :)

Comment: I would simply loop through the array with a counter, if status changes log the time and counter, then reset the counter.  What kind of code do you have so far?

Comment: Well, its out of an hdf5-database, which is normally adressed with a package a college wrote. So the normal way is like: output_filter = user_filter("numpy.ma.where(a1 >= p0,a0,p1)", [sensor,condition_sensor], parameters=[condition,othervalue]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, finally i got i for myself. But millions of thanks to the answer of Joe Kington, which highly inspired me and teached me the whole stuff :)

#### Script

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    # Generate some data...
    t = np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 30)
    x = np.sin(t)
    condition = np.where(x>0,1,0)
    
    onarray,offarray = on_off_times(condition)

    print "Condition: ",condition
    print "Ontimes:   ",onarray
    print "Offtimes:  ",offarray
    
        
def on_off_times(condition):
        
    changing=np.diff(condition)         #complete array, -1 when tunring off, +1 when turning on
    idx, = changing.nonzero()           #Indices of changepoints
    times=np.diff(idx)              #'Times' between changes
    times=np.r_[0,times]            # The first time can't be calculated ->is set to 0
    
    ontimes=np.where(changing[idx]<0,times,False)   #When turning off: Was Ontime (times-array with "False" instead of offtimes)
    offtimes=np.where(changing[idx]>0,times,False)  #When turning on:  Was Offtime
    
    onarray=np.r_[changing.copy(),0]            #copy the array with all the values and add 1(to have an "empty" array of the right size)
    offarray=np.r_[changing.copy(),0]
    
    np.put(onarray,idx,ontimes)         #Put the times into it (at the changepoints)
    np.put(offarray,idx,offtimes)

    return onarray,offarray
    
main()
```

Yields in:

```
Condition:  [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
Ontimes:    [0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0]
Offtimes:   [0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Things to mention:

- Yes, the code gives another output as I requested in my Question..
  Sorry for beeing unprecise, but the output the function gives is what
  i finally need.
- Now i just have to get the zeros in the Outputs
  masked, which will be easy.
- If anybody has a nicer way to put() the data in a new array ,please edit :)
- How to link to the user Joe? Or how to thank him?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a boolean array and you want to find the start and stop of contiguous regions.

It's far better to avoid looping over each item of a numpy array.

There are a few different ways of doing it, but I usually do something similar to this (which I probably originally got from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg13930.html)):

```
import numpy as np
def contiguous_regions(condition):
    """Finds contiguous True regions of the boolean array "condition". Returns
    a 2D array where the first column is the start index of the region and the
    second column is the end index."""

    # Find the indicies of changes in "condition"
    idx, = np.diff(condition).nonzero()

    # Prepend or append the start or end indicies to "idx"
    # if there's a block of "True"'s at the start or end...
    if condition[0]:
        idx = np.r_[0, idx]
    if condition[-1]:
        idx = np.r_[idx, len(condition)-1]

    return idx.reshape((-1,2))
```

As a quick example:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    # Generate some data...
    t = np.linspace(0, 6*np.pi, 100)
    x = np.sin(t)
    condition = x > 0

    regions = contiguous_regions(condition)
    lengths = regions[:,1] - regions[:,0]

    for reg, length in zip(regions, lengths):
        print 'Condition was True for {0} seconds'.format(length)
        print '    From time {0}s to {1}s'.format(*reg)

def contiguous_regions(condition):
    idx, = np.diff(condition).nonzero()

    if condition[0]:
        idx = np.r_[0, idx]
    if condition[-1]:
        idx = np.r_[idx, len(condition)-1]

    return idx.reshape((-1,2))

main()
```

This yields:

```
Condition was True for 16 seconds
    From time 0s to 16s
Condition was True for 16 seconds
    From time 33s to 49s
Condition was True for 16 seconds
    From time 66s to 82s
```

Comment: Thanks. that's it! Took me quite a while to understand, but now i even managed to extend the method to return the false-regions, too. (I have the code ready, but as i'm new to stackoverflow, i don't know where to put it. Here, in this comment field? Or rather making a new answer??)

Comment: Okay, now I ran it over my original data, which is a masked array. And there it doesn't work: Several times, there's a status change in a masked period - so the contiguous_regions doesn't get it. So in the following values, the onregions an offregions are mixed up :( --> If I have 0/1-Values instead of Bool, 'np.diff()' gives '-1' and '+1'. But how to proceed?

Comment: It won't work for masked arrays. I should have read your question a bit more closely.  The quick workaround is to operate on the condensed version of the array. E.g. `condition = x.compressed() > threshold` (or whatever applies in your case)

Answer (score 0):

I would have done this the following way:

```
# read data from file
dt = {'names' : ('ts', 'state'), 'formats' : ('S5','i4')}
data = np.loadtxt(datafn, dtype = dt)
# minutes counter
mc = 1
# current state, current timestamp
cs = data[0]['state']
ct = data[0]['ts']
# states dictionary
states = {1 : [], 0 : []}

for minute in data[1:]:
    if cs != minute['state']:
        states[cs].append([ct, mc])
        mc = 0
        cs = minute['state']
        ct = minute['ts']
    else:
        mc += 1
# Printing the result
print 'On time'
for [ts, mc] in states[1]:
     print '%s\t%i' % (ts, mc)
print 'Off time'
for [ts, mc] in states[0]:
     print '%s\t%i' % (ts, mc)
```

Extremely untested but you can get the logic.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeah, could be a solution.  But as I already have the data in an numpy.ma-array (the example above was just to clarify my problem), isn't there any numpy-function which could handle this?

Comment: I haven't heard of one. Couldn't you iterate over non-masked values of a ma-array?

Answer (score 0):

#### (Possible) Answer

You could try this:

```
Since = 0
for i in range(1, Data.shape[0]):
    #Switched off
    if Data[i, 1] == 0.0 and Data[i - 1, 1] == 1.0:
        print "{0} for {1}min".format(Data[i, 0], i - Since)
    #Switched on
    elif Data[i, 1] == 1.0 and Data[i - 1, 1] == 0.0:
        Since = i
```

You loop through the hole array (`Data`) which has in its first column the time stamps and in its second column a `1.0` or `0.0` depending if the heater was on or off.

You detect the change of state looking at the actual on/off value and the previous one. Depending on those two values you see if the heater was `Switched off` or `Switched on`. All you need to do then is to save the value of the current index in `Since` and you get the time the heater was switched on.

#### Script

With the following script you can set up a data array and run the code above and see how it works:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

#Setting up OnOff array
OnOff = np.concatenate((np.zeros((7,)), np.ones((20,)), np.zeros((3,)), np.ones((5,)), np.zeros((4,)), np.ones((16,)), np.zeros((2,)), np.ones((2,)), np.zeros((1,))))

#Setting up time array
start = datetime.time(12, 00)
TimeStamps = []

for i in range(OnOff.size):
    TimeStamps.append(datetime.time(12 + i/60, np.mod(i, 60)))

TimeStamps = np.array(TimeStamps)

#Concatenating both arrays to a single array
Data = np.hstack((np.reshape(TimeStamps, (TimeStamps.size, 1)), np.reshape(OnOff, (OnOff.size, 1))))

Since = 0
for i in range(1, Data.shape[0]):
    #Switched off
    if Data[i, 1] == 0.0 and Data[i - 1, 1] == 1.0:
        print "{0} for {1}min".format(Data[i, 0], i - Since)
    #Switched on
    elif Data[i, 1] == 1.0 and Data[i - 1, 1] == 0.0:
        Since = i
```

The output is

```
12:27:00 for 20min
12:35:00 for 5min
12:55:00 for 16min
12:59:00 for 2min
```